# Block an IP range with FreeBSD's 'route add'

Tags: unix, ip, freebsd, route

To block a single IP address I'm using the following:

```
/sbin/route add -host 192.168.0.0 127.0.0.1
```

Is it possible to block an range of the IP addresses using the `route`?

I have tried the tips found on google like:

```
/sbin/route add 192.168.0.0/24
/sbin/route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 -blackhole
```

But none of them seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Why are you not using one of the three built-in firewalls??

Answer (score 4):

Blackholing an IP:

```
/sbin/route add 192.168.0.1 127.0.0.1 -blackhole
```

Blackholing a range:

```
/sbin/route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 127.0.0.1 -blackhole
```

To make it permanent edit /etc/rc.conf:

```
static_routes=”d1 d2″
route_d1=”-net 192.168.0.0/16 127.0.0.1 -blackhole”
route_d2=”-net 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.1 -blackhole”
```